# getting error while unraring with patoolib on Python

Tags: python

This code is just for testing purposes ( learning here )

Checks for files on a directory, if they end with .rar it prints its name, decompresses the file and calls another function that prints the name again.

The code :

```
import os, patoolib

path = "/root/tree/down/"


def cutext(f):
    print (f)


def unrar():
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if f.endswith('.rar'):
            print(f)
            patoolib.extract_archive(f, outdir="/root/tree/def")
            cutext(f)

unrar()
```

The output error ( reads the file but does not decompresses it ) :

```
root@debian:~# python autotube.py
Ravi Shankar - Shankar Family & Friends (2010) [FLAC].rar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autotube.py", line 17, in <module>
    unrar()
  File "autotube.py", line 14, in unrar
    patoolib.extract_archive(f, outdir="/root/tree/def")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/patoolib/__init__.py", line 676, in extract_archive
    util.check_existing_filename(archive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/patoolib/util.py", line 390, in check_existing_filename
    raise PatoolError("file `%s' was not found" % filename)
patoolib.util.PatoolError: file `Ravi Shankar - Shankar Family & Friends (2010) [FLAC].rar' was not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
patoolib.util.PatoolError: file `Ravi Shankar - Shankar Family & Friends (2010) [FLAC].rar' was not found
```

This suggests the program can not find the file. You are doing `listdir()` on `"/root/tree/down/"` but when you're passing the file to `extract_archive`, you're just passing the file name `f` which does not include the full path. So if there's a file  `/root/tree/down/myarchive.rar`, you're just passing `myarchive.rar`.
So the program tries to find it in the same directory (current working directory) but can not find it since it's not here.

Please update your code to pass the full path:

```
def unrar():
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if f.endswith('.rar'):
            print(f)
            patoolib.extract_archive(os.path.join(path,f), outdir="/root/tree/def")
            cutext(f)
```

The `os.path.join` should construct the full path to the file and pass it. Now your program should work.

Comment: Ok, got it. os.path.join joins the path and the filename. But now, after extracting, I call the cutext function, pass the variable to it, and it does not print the name of (f) again.

Comment: Can you post what you expect and what you get?

Comment: The output is too long to post here, but the last line is a sucessful decompress message : `patoolib.util.PatoolError: Command `['/usr/bin/unrar', 'x', '--', '/root/tree/down/Ravi Shankar - Shankar Family & Friends (2010) [FLAC].rar']' returned non-zero exit status 1` And I expect it to after compressing, call cutext function and print (f) again.